# Highcharts Drilldown Multiple Graphs

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts

I have a page which includes a pie graph and a column graph using highcharts.

Very similiar to this example here,

http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/Vf3yT/

The issue I'm having which can be seen in the example aswell, is
If I click on an item in the column graph to drilldown, I get "Back to Overview", I click it, and it takes me back no problem.

However, its when you try to drill down two graphs at the same time I get an issue. If I click on at item in column graph and then in the pie graph, and try to drill back up on column, it thinks the column graph has drilled down twice. and If I drill up twice on the column graph, I am then unable to drill up on the pie graph.

The graphs are rendered in different divs, using different options like so

```
optionsColumn.chart.renderTo = 'graph';
optionsColumn.chart.type = 'column';
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(optionsColumn);

optionsPie.chart.renderTo = 'graphPie';
optionsPie.chart.type = 'pie';
var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart(optionsPie);
```

The issue also exists in the example and I have been unsuccessful in finding a fix for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in version from jsfiddle, it's already fixed on master branch, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Vf3yT/354/

```
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.src.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. The Demo link in the drilldown.Js points to the one I provided which has those versions of drilldown and highcharts which I then used. Much appreciated.